# Is PowerVM a full operating system? (And other clarifications.)

Tags: virtual-machine, aix

I have a few things that I was hoping someone with more experience could clarify in regards to using PowerVM (specifically to virtualise via LPARs AIX).

So here is what I think I understand regarding PowerVM/LPAR's etc:

- PowerVM itself (i.e. the Hyper-visor/firmware) has no hostname or IP Address of it's own (Excluding things like RSA cards).
- PowerVM is just a hyper-visor/firmware and not a full Operating System.
- Resources are controlled/distributed to the individual LPAR OS's via a VIOS LPAR, which in turn is managed by either a HMC and/or an IVM.

Now I'm not overly familiar with IBM virtualisation (More used to Windows/Linux/Solaris) so what I was looking for is if someone could either confirm or clarify these points for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are more-or-less correct on all 3 points.

- PowerVM is the hypervisor. It has redundant service processors that do the work of RSA cards you'd find in the intel systems. There are 3 tiers of PowerVM each providing additional functionality on the system. (More LPARs, Partition Mobility, etc)
- There is no operating system to manage for PowerVM.
- VIOs do not control the client (AIX/Linux) LPARs, they simply provide virtualized I/O (network, vscsi, FCP). The PowerVM hypervisor is responsible for the control. The HMC/IVM is a window to PowerVM and allows you to manage the running resources on the system.

See an [Introduction to Virtualization on Power](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/virtualization/Introduction+to+Virtualization+on+Power) on the IBM PowerVM Wiki. It provides some introductory details about PowerVM, and I'd recommend you dig a bit more in the main page of that wiki, there are a lot of great articles on there.